# Find occurrence of stringin a log file and replace it

Tags: python

I have a log file with the following sample data:

```
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.127812] First='Aiden' Last='Adams' Gender='1' Identifier='68D8867BDDCF97FB' DOB ="10/9/1994" PCP_NPI='111111111' PCP_Name='Howell, Sarah' TIN='121212121' TIN_Name='Local Care MDs' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='5 Harvard St. ' Address2='' City='Bellmore' State='NY' Zip='11710' Phone1='(516) 794-9644' 
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.127969] First='Aubrey' Last='Adams' Gender='2' Identifier='B474A3E066EC5E97' DOB='6/5/1946' PCP_NPI='777777777' PCP_Name='Miller, Daniel' TIN='454545454' TIN_Name='Miller Medical Center' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='400 Columbia Ave. ' Address2='' City='Garden City' State='NY' Zip='11530' Phone1='(516) 024-9814' 
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128045] First='Lily' Last='Adams' Gender='2' Identifier='FE3C94F9E9E2015C' DOB='12/19/1939' PCP_NPI='444444444' PCP_Name='Medina, Hannah' TIN='232323232' TIN_Name='Physicians First LLC' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='33 Newbridge Drive ' Address2='Suite 84' City='Franklin Square' State='NY' Zip='11010' Phone1='(516) 490-1739' 
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128096] First='Luke' Last='Adams' Gender='1' Identifier='482FEBA25C9147BF' DOB='3/22/1951' PCP_NPI='555555555' PCP_Name='Franklin, Emma' TIN='232323232' TIN_Name='Physicians First LLC' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='53 Oxford Ave. ' Address2='' City='Kingston' State='NY' Zip='12401' Phone1='(845) 240-2310' 
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128144] First='Adalyn' Last='Aguilar' Gender='2' Identifier='B077BE5E588AA1B0' DOB='8/14/1947' PCP_NPI='666666666' PCP_Name='Hoffman, Daniel' TIN='343434343' TIN_Name='Hoffman Medical Associates' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='1 Strawberry St. ' Address2='' City='Clifton Park' State='NY' Zip='12065' Phone1='(518) 760-1789'
```

I have to detect the DOB =' ' value and replace it in this format: DOB='X/X/YEAR'
This is a sample output:

```
[2018-04-19 12:58:59.127969] First='Aubrey' Last='Adams' Gender='2' Identifier='B474A3E066EC5E97' DOB='X/X/1946' PCP_NPI='777777777' PCP_Name='Miller, Daniel' TIN='454545454' TIN_Name='Miller Medical Center' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='400 Columbia Ave. ' Address2='' City='Garden City' State='NY' Zip='11530' Phone1='(516) 024-9814'
```

I'm trying to replace the date and month in DOB with X

I tried using regex, but it wasn't matching 'DOB='. This is the regex I used for date

```regex
(^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\.|-|/)([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\.|-|/)([0-9][0-9]|19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])$)
```

Comment: The DOB values are already in that format.  Or are you LITERALLY trying to shroud the month and day?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I'm trying to cut or shroud the month and date and replace with 'X'

Comment: So, that regex simply doesn't include `DOB=` in it... Have you tried adding it?

Comment: Why are there start- and end-of-line markers in the regex? (`^` and `$`)

Comment: @wjandrea Maybe that's where I screwed up. If you could help me create a regex for this, that would be helpful

Comment: Well, what's your question exactly? That regex obviously isn't going to work, so do you have a specific question about it? If you need to learn regex overall, that's outside the scope of this site, but you might try the official Python [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), and there are lots of other great resources. For tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is this pattern with `re.sub`

check [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BVfIpc/1)

```
import re

lst = ["[2018-04-19 12:58:59.127812] First='Aiden' Last='Adams' Gender='1' Identifier='68D8867BDDCF97FB' DOB='10/9/1994' PCP_NPI='111111111' PCP_Name='Howell, Sarah' TIN='121212121' TIN_Name='Local Care MDs' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='5 Harvard St. ' Address2='' City='Bellmore' State='NY' Zip='11710' Phone1='(516) 794-9644'",
"[2018-04-19 12:58:59.127969] First='Aubrey' Last='Adams' Gender='2' Identifier='B474A3E066EC5E97' DOB='6/5/1946' PCP_NPI='777777777' PCP_Name='Miller, Daniel' TIN='454545454' TIN_Name='Miller Medical Center' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='400 Columbia Ave. ' Address2='' City='Garden City' State='NY' Zip='11530' Phone1='(516) 024-9814'",
"[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128045] First='Lily' Last='Adams' Gender='2' Identifier='FE3C94F9E9E2015C' DOB='12/19/1939' PCP_NPI='444444444' PCP_Name='Medina, Hannah' TIN='232323232' TIN_Name='Physicians First LLC' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='33 Newbridge Drive ' Address2='Suite 84' City='Franklin Square' State='NY' Zip='11010' Phone1='(516) 490-1739'",
"[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128096] First='Luke' Last='Adams' Gender='1' Identifier='482FEBA25C9147BF' DOB='3/22/1951' PCP_NPI='555555555' PCP_Name='Franklin, Emma' TIN='232323232' TIN_Name='Physicians First LLC' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='53 Oxford Ave. ' Address2='' City='Kingston' State='NY' Zip='12401' Phone1='(845) 240-2310'",
"[2018-04-19 12:58:59.128144] First='Adalyn' Last='Aguilar' Gender='2' Identifier='B077BE5E588AA1B0' DOB='8/14/1947' PCP_NPI='666666666' PCP_Name='Hoffman, Daniel' TIN='343434343' TIN_Name='Hoffman Medical Associates' ApplyMonth='201801' LOB='M' Address1='1 Strawberry St. ' Address2='' City='Clifton Park' State='NY' Zip='12065' Phone1='(518) 760-1789'"]

pattern = r"(?<=DOB)\s?='(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})(?=')"
for s in lst:
    out = re.sub(pattern, r"X/X/\3", s)
    print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
outstr = re.sub( r"DOB=\d\d?/\d\d?/", "DOB=X/X/", instr )
```

will do the job.  No heavy lifting is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using back references in vim, hope it works for you.

```
%s/\(DOB.*\)\(=*[^0-9]\)\([0-9].*\)\/\([0-9].*\)\/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2X\/X\/\5/g
```